# Jolt : How to extract repeatative element from list of objects and add once at the root level

Tags: json, jolt

My Input Sample JSON, it has repetitive "total" and "nextpage" elements in each object array and all are having same values. I need to display the "total" and "nextpage" elements at the top level,below "types" key and remove the "total" and "nextpage" elements from the rest of the JSON document.

```
{
  "types": {
    "coupontype1": [
      {
        "code": "XXX",
        "exp_dt": "2020-01-01",
        "total": 3,
        "nextPage": "urllink"
      },
      {
        "code": "YYY",
        "exp_dt": "2019-12-01",
        "total": 3,
        "nextPage": "urllink"
      }
    ],
    "coupontype2": [
      {
        "code": "ZZZ",
        "exp_dt": "2020-01-01",
        "total": 3,
        "nextPage": "urllink"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected output JSON

```
{
  "types": {
    "total": 3,
    "nextPage": "urllink"
    "coupontype1": [
      {
        "code": "XXX",
        "exp_dt": "2020-01-01"
      },
      {
        "code": "YYY",
        "exp_dt": "2019-12-01"
      }
    ],
    "coupontype2": [
      {
        "code": "ZZZ",
        "exp_dt": "2020-01-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I received a complex JSON structure from upstream component and structured as my input JSON using JOLT schema, Kindly help me to draft the JOLT schema for the above requirement. I could not find documents explaining JOLT schema design. Trying out trial and errors in JOLT demo and referring examples to achieve the same. but I am stuck at this scenario completely.

Comment: I tried this JOLT spec but it completely removed the rest of the JSON,[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "types": {
        "totalcount": 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "types": {
        "coupontype1": {
          "0": {
            "total": "totalcount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments inline for explanation:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "types": {
        // get but don't match so next copy works. 
        // Using value of coupontype1.0.total|nextPage and set to types
        "@(coupontype1)": {
          "0": {
            "total": "types.&",
            "nextPage": "types.&"
          }
        },
        // copy everything
        "*": {
          "@": "types.&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //remove total and nextPage
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "types": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "total": "",
            "nextPage": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```